# django get filtered by parameter

Tags: django, filter

The site I am building has 6 profiles (desks) and these are accessed via buttons at the top of the page using:

```
path('home/<slug:slug>/', HomeView.as_view(), name='homepage')
```

and is accessed by a button with:

```
{% url 'homepage', slug=desk.slug %}
```

So is filtered in the queryset. How can I access what that value so I can use it in the template for styling purposes? basically I want to highlight the desk button on the page so the user has visual feedback on where he is. Is there a way to do this nicely, as currently the only way I can think of doing this is to use:

```
{% request.url %}
```

and then split off the end of the url, but that seems like a nasty hack to me. Unfortunately google can't get past the word filter so all I get is django-filter documentation and issues.

UPDATE: adding view:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = pcc_homepage/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['desks'] = Desk.objects.all()
        context['updates'] = Update.objects.all().order_by('-published')
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Handover.objects.filter(desk__slug=self.kwargs['slug']).order_by('-published')
```

Comment: You can obtain the slug in the template with `slug`, so `{{ slug }}` will print the slug.

Comment: That assumes that `slug` is being passed in through the template context.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the view. As you can see, the model for desks is in the context, but it is filtered in done in the get_queryset, can I get it from there, or do I have to swap the updates with the handover, so that the filtered slug goes through the context?